# Difference between print!() and println!()

Tags: rust, input, visual-c++, printing, io

When i use this code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut buff: String = String::new();

    println!("Welcome to guessing game!");
    let min_bottom: i32;
    loop{
        println!("Enter bottom border: ");
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut buff) {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Failed to read string");
                continue;
            }
        }
        match buff.trim().parse() {
            Ok(val) => {
                min_bottom = val;
                break;
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Incorrect string!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{min_bottom}")
}
```

I have next output(>> is my input):

```
Welcome to guessing game!
Enter bottom border:
>> 123
123
```

BUT when i replace `println!("Enter bottom border: ");` to `print!("Enter bottom border: ");` I have next output:

```
Welcome to guessing game!
>> 123
Enter bottom border: 123
```

What happens?
What is the difference between print!() and println!() in my case?

I actually don`t know what happens

Comment: `println!("foo")` is the same as `print!("foo\n")` - that is, it inserts a newline at the end.

Comment: I do notice that you aren't clearing `buff` before reading the next line. You should have a `buff.clear()` somewhere in there.

Comment: This is a very common issue. `println` and `print` only differ in the newline, but stdout needs to be flushed to see the results. Most languages do this for you, and newlines automatically invoke a flush, which is why `println` works fine.